# Vs code studio not connecting to salesforce

Tags: visual-studio-code, salesforce, connection, command-line-interface

I am trying to connect my VS Code studio to salesforce and it is giving me an error

```
"SFDX: Authorize an Org failed to run"

Node.js v20.8.1
 sfdx org:login:web --alias vscodeOrg --instance-url https://login.salesforce.com --set-default
 ended with exit code 1
```

I have uninstalled VS Code and installed again.

Answer (score 0):

can you add to the end the flags in the terminal?

```
--dev-debug
```

To see the full output and to get more info about the log.